# How to animate an icon above a menu- jquery

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I am making a website and for the menu i want an icon above the menu items to slide along when you hover over the menu links.

I have seen menus where you hover and you get a sliding action on rollover to highlight the menu item, but was wondering if you could place an image above this?

I hope my questions clear!  Thankyou.

Comment: Please read the site FAQ. Questions are expected to be explicit and include code when possible. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? - http://www.geektantra.com/projects/jquery-sliding-menu/

If so, you can download the JQuery plugin from http://www.geektantra.com/2010/02/jquery-sliding-menu/

It's also called JQuery Lavalamp. You can find out more here - http://nixboxdesigns.com/projects/jquery-lavalamp/

LavaLamp also has a demo page here - http://nixboxdesigns.com/projects/jquery-lavalamp/demos.php